# How to assign blocks to particular regions on theme install?

Tags: 8, blocks, theming

Drupal 8 provides some blocks by default. Eg. `Site Branding`, `Main Navigation`, `Powered by Drupal`, `Search` etc.

I have created a theme that has `Site branding` & `Main Navigation` named regions in which corresponding blocks can be placed.

When I enable my theme, `Site Branding` & `Main Navigation` blocks are placed in `Header` & `First Sidebar` region of my theme by default respectively.

How can I place `Site Branding` & `Main Navigation` blocks to their respective regions by default on theme install?

Comment: You have to create block instances which are configuration objects and put them into your theme's config/install directory.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, you should change each desired block region you want manually at `Administration>Structure>Block layout Tab` and then go to the config export function at:
`Administration>Configuration>Development>Configuration synchronization>Export Tab>Single item` to export each the block settings for your theme.
Then you should take a look at to the generated YAML files and placed that in a new folder within your theme at `/config/install`. you then uninstalled the theme and then reinstalled it as the default.

Summary:
1. Install `MY_THEME`
2. Place the blocks in the desired regions
3. Export config files and remove from them `uuid` and core config hash
for example `Site Branding` block `block.block.MY_THEME_branding.yml` file

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - system
  theme:
    - DEPENDENT_THEME
id: MY_THEME_branding
theme: MY_THEME
region: site_branding
weight: 0
provider: null
plugin: system_branding_block
settings:
  id: system_branding_block
  label: 'Site branding'
  provider: system
  label_display: '0'
  use_site_logo: true
  use_site_name: true
  use_site_slogan: true
visibility: {  }
```

4. Place config files to `MY_THEME/config/optional` or `MY_THEME/config/install` directory (if you're absolutely sure all dependencies are met)
5. Uninstall `MY_THEME` and clear all caches
6. Reinstall `MY_THEME` again

Answer (score 7):

Found the answer:

This can be done by adding a yml file (block instance) for each block in the `theme/config/install` folder.

For eg., To assign the `Site Branding` block (machine name `system_branding_block`) to the `Site Branding` region (machine name `site_branding`) add the following code in the `config/install/block.block.THEME_NAME_branding.yml` file:

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - system
  theme:
    - DEPENDENT_THEME
id: THEME_NAME_branding
theme: THEME_NAME
region: site_branding
weight: 0
provider: null
plugin: system_branding_block
settings:
  id: system_branding_block
  label: 'Site branding'
  provider: system
  label_display: '0'
  use_site_logo: true
  use_site_name: true
  use_site_slogan: true
visibility: {  }
```